# Pilot light continually burning

Tags: furnace, gas

The pilot light on my gas fire usually goes out once the fire is lit and I have released the switch. Now for some reason the pilot lite remains lit and doesn't go out until I turn the fire off. This is unusual as the pilot light has never continually burned while the fire is burning. What would cause this to happen? Cheers Brent.

Comment: how is the main burner supposed to light if there is no pilot light? ... i think that you are remembering wrong about the pilot light "usually going out"

Comment: If you provide the manufacturer and model number for the gas fire(place?), someone can help you find the manual and confirm whether this is expected behavior or not.

Answer (score 3):

Gas fired appliances usually have a standing pilot that is monitored or one of several types of igniters, spark igniters usually you can hear the click, click click, hot surface igniter several types here coils if nichrome wires that get red hot and a carbon like material that gets hot and ignites the gas all 3 that ignite the main burner do not have a pilot. The type that has a standing pilot the pilot is always lit.

Standing pilots are going out of style because of the constant use of gas. The bummer about this is standing pilots are much more reliable than any of the other methods.

If you notice the gas going off I believe you are remembering the temp being made and the main burner shutting down. As if the pilot shuts down this will normally cause the thermocouple to cool and will normally shut the gas down unless there is a system to monitor the flame. With the information provided I believe you are not accurate in your memory of events but a model number would help verify the normal operation.